# Update column value of a table when the value of another table changes

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers, oracle-apex

I have 3 tables (`Inventory`, `OrderMaster`, `OrderDetail`). In the table `Inventory` I have *ID_PRODUCT* and *quantity_inventory* columns. In the table `OrderMaster` I have `ID_ORDER` and `ID_STATE_OF_ORDER` (all rows are 3 at the start). Last, but not least, inthe table `OrderDetail` I have *ID_ORDER*, *ID_PRODUCT* and *quantity_ordered*.

I need a trigger that when the *ID_STATE_OF_ORDER* in `OrderMaster` changes to 1, then *quanity_inventory* in the table `Inventory` will be the current amount minus *quantity_ordered*

The current trigger I have is

```sql
create or replace trigger Inventory_switch   
  AFTER UPDATE on OrderMaster            
  Begin 
    UPDATE Inventory
        SET quantity_inventory = 
        (SELECT Inventory.quantity_inventory - OrderDetail.quantity_ordered
        FROM Inventory, OrderDetail, OrderMaster
        WHERE Inventory.ID_PRODUCT = OrderDetail.ID_PRODUCT AND
            OrderMaster.ID_ORDER = OrderDetail.ID_ORDER AND
            OrderMaster.ID_STATE_OF_ORDER = 1);
End;
```

This code updates all the rows in `Inventory` regardless of the conditions I've entered.

Please, I would apreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which database are you really using? Tag says "MySQL", but PL/SQL tag is related to **Oracle**, not MySQL.

Comment: Im using Oracle. My mistake, I am new to Oracle so it gets a bit confusing at times

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it is Oracle, then:

- you're missing the `FOR EACH ROW` clause (so that you'd update rows which are related to `id_order` whose values have been updated)
- reference to `:new` pseudorecord
- `when` clause, so that you wouldn't update anything if state of order isn't 1
- `exists` clause, so that you wouldn't update the whole table but only affected rows

Something like this:

```
create or replace trigger inventory_switch
  after update of id_state_of_order on ordermaster
  for each row
  when (new.id_state_of_order = 1
        and
        nvl(old.id_state_of_order, 0) <> 1
       )
begin
  update inventory i
  set
    i.quantity_inventory = i.quantity_inventory -
      (select sum(od.quantity_ordered)
       from orderdetail od
       where od.id_product = i.id_product
       and od.id_order = :new.id_order
      )
    where exists
      (select null
       from orderdetail od
       where od.id_product = i.id_product
       and od.id_order = :new.id_order
      );
end inventory_switch;
/
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! unfortunately the code still updates every row of inventory

Comment: The points are correct. The subquery was not correctly corelated, though. I've made some amendments and think the trigger should work now. In this update statment we have about the same subquery twice. In theory, this can be avoided with an updatable query instead, but in my experience Oracle fails with updatable queries involving aggregation.

Comment: Im so sorry if being too annoying and I really apreciate the help, but I get a missing right parenthesis error.

Comment: Fixed it. Instead of the second where in the select sections an and was ment to follow. Now it works perfectly. Thank you both so much!